# Is it possible to reduce an image's depth using PIL?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Is it possible to reduce the depth of an image using PIL? Say like going to 4bpp from a regular 8bpp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily convert image modes (just call `im.convert(newmode)` on an image object `im`, it will give you a new image of the new required mode), but there's no mode for "4bpp"; the modes supported are listed [here](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/concepts.htm) in the [*The Python Imaging Library Handbook*](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the **changeColorDepth** function in **ufp.image** module.
this function only can reduce color depth(bpp)

```
import ufp.image
import PIL
im = PIL.Image.open('test.png')
ufp.image.changeColorDepth(im, 16) # change to 4bpp(this function change original PIL.Image object)
im.save('changed.png')
```

Comment: -1 just because this is an unmaintained package whose docs are *in part* only available in Korean and *in part* no longer easily available at all because they've been replaced with a redirect to Rick Astley's *Never Gonna Give You Up* on YouTube. Maybe the underlying code is nonetheless good but IMO it'd be preferable to quote the implementation of the relevant functions rather than suggest depending on an unmaintained package whose docs most readers can't understand without Google Translate.